# Wordpress query with 19000+ products

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem with my Wordpress Query.

What I'm try to do:

I have CSV file with products data(name, price, stock, sku etc.)
And I want to import this file, but when I'm trying to get Product ID by SKU my query is too high for my server, but I'm doing some stupid idea : in foreach I'm trying to get all product_id.

It's possible to split my wp query without killing my server?
I'm trying sleep but this is no result...

My code is here:

```
    public function new_import_stock_prices(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;

    if ( !function_exists( 'wc_get_product_id_by_sku' ) ) { 
        require_once '/includes/wc-product-functions.php'; 
    } 

    echo '<h1>Import stanów magazynowych i cen z pliku CSV </h1>';
    echo '<h4>Plik pobierany jest z netis/products.csv</h4>';
    $fn = 'https://e-xxxxx.pl/xxx/products.csv';
    $file_array = file($fn);
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>LP</td>';
    echo '<td>Nazwa</td>';
    echo '<td>SKU</td>';
    echo '<td>Stan magazynowy</td>';
    echo '<td>Cena</td>';
    echo '<td>Product ID</td>';
    $i = 1;
    if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    foreach ($file_array as $line_number =>&$line)
        {
            if ($line_number > 0 && $line_number % 10 == 0) {

                $row2=explode('|',$line);
                $sku = $row2[1];
                // get the product ID from the SKU
                $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );        
                // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
                $product = new WC_Product( $product_id );

                //Get product stock quantity and stock status
                $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
                $stock_status   = $product->get_stock_status();

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row2[0].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row2[1].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row2[5].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row2[2].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$product_id.'</td>';

                echo '</tr>';
                $i = $i +1;
                sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

BTW. my wp_postmeta table has ~900 000+ records :O

Comment: `I'm trying sleep but this is no result...` that's the opposite of what you want to do.  3(ish) things will hurt you here `memory_limit` and `time_limit` and the buffer for the browser. You can change them a bit maybe, but they are poor fixes.

Comment: `And I want to import this file,`  I don't see where you are saving it (unless I missed `WC_Product::save()` somewhere), I see you outputting it.  So do you want to output it or save it.

Comment: Memory limit is 10240m and time limit is 1000

Comment: So, your trying to read the whole file at one time, and besides that your severs memory has nothing to do with a clients memory for their browser.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix first I want to display all products id, to check if it's correct. Next step is change stock, price and saving products. It's my first plugin :)

Comment: It's simply too much data to do at one time, not much you can do about it.  If the client is involved you have no control over their stuff.  And if its a plugin, you may have no control over the server if you plan to publish it.

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to import this file

I don't see any code for importing, I see code for displaying. Assuming by import, you mean display:

What's probably happening is one of a few things.

- your running out of memory (you should get an error for this)

  - don't use `file($fn)` use file functions that open the file and read line by line, such as `fgetcsv`
- your running out of time

  - not much you can do about this, except send less data
- your overwhelming the browser buffer by sending to much output.

  - again not much you can do about this but send less data.

The only real solution (Assuming by import, you mean display) is to page the data.

Now even in a file you can page the data, but I would suggest using SQLFileObject instead of the procedural file functions.  That said you can page using the procedural style but its by Byte Offset, not page number.

While I can't code an entire paging system I can give you some tips:

For example

```
//hard to tell how many lines in the file
$fn = 'https://e-xxxxx.pl/xxx/products.csv';
$f = fopen($fn, 'r');
fseek($f, $_GET['offset']); //seek to a byte offset
$i=0;
while(!feof($f) && ($row=fgetcsv($f)) && null !== $row[0]){

   if($i==10)
       $offset = ftell($f); //get byte offset

   ++$i;
}
```

`ftell` and `fseek` allow you get or move the file pointer (in bytes).  So you can start reading from a predefined offset that you can pass around in the url ... etc.

You can do the same thing with SplFileObject, but a bit better.

```
try {
    $fn = 'https://e-xxxxx.pl/xxx/products.csv';
    $csv  = new SplFileObject($fn, 'r');
} catch (RuntimeException $e ) {
    printf("Error openning csv: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
}

$csv->seek($_GET['line']); //seek to a predefined line

while(!$csv->eof() && ($row = $csv->fgetcsv()) && null !== $row[0]) {
    if(($csv->key()-$_GET['line'])==10) 
        $line = $csv->key(); //get line offset
   ++$i;
}
```

The main advantage of SPL is you can use the row number, which is much easier to work with.

You can also get the total number of lines in a file like this

```
$csv->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);
$total = $csv->key();
$csv->rewind(); //or $csv->seek($_GET['line'])
```

Basically this seeks to the largest possible INT PHP can handle, but because the file is a fixed length, it puts the pointer at the end of the file, then using `key` we can get the line number.  Then we simply rewind to where we want to read from.

I mention the total number of rows because in paging it's nice to be able to show that.

**Another option (to display)**

Besides paging is to output the page without buffering.

```
 // Turn off output buffering
 ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
 // Turn off PHP output compression
 ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

 //Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
 //ob_end_flush();
 while (ob_get_level()) ob_end_flush();

 // Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
 ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
 ob_implicit_flush(true);
```

Combine this with one of the methods I showed above to read the file 1 line at a time, and you may be able to eventually read all that data out.

**Saving**

For saving the data, your probably going to need to break it into batches, the same thing with paging can be done here (using offset or line).  So that you only import a couple thousand rows at a time.  I would also recommend not outputting the data, because you can give the browser more buffer then it can handle and lock it up.  However if you page the data you can break it into small enough chunks that the browser can handle it.

You can even automate this using successive AJAX calls.  Basically you would call the code on the backend to save a certain number of rows (x). The sever would respond, and then you would make another call for (x) more rows, save & repeat.

> I want to display all products id, to check if it's correct. Next step is change stock, price and saving products

It would be easier to do this work in something like excel, just from a data entry standpoint, no one wants to edit thousands of rows on a web page and then have their session time out or something like that.

Hope that helps.